# Switching screens by dragging over the touch screen

Tags: android

I had tried a code for Switching Screen by dragging over the touch screen..but it gives an error...can anyone please check what mistake i have done in the code..and error arise at

> vf.setInAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
>   R.anim.push_left_in));
>   vf.setInAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
>   R.anim.push_left_out));

code for .xml file

```
<ViewFlipper android:id="@+id/details"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">  

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#ffffff">

        <TextView android:id="@+id/tv_country"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="18px"
            android:text="Country" >
        </TextView>
        <Spinner android:text=""
            android:id="@+id/spinner_country"
            android:layout_width="200px"
            android:layout_height="55px">
        </Spinner>
    </LinearLayout> 

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#ffffff">

        <TextView android:id="@+id/tv_income"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="18px"
            android:text="Income" >
        </TextView>
        <EditText android:text=""
            android:id="@+id/et_income"
            android:layout_width="200px"
            android:layout_height="55px">
        </EditText>
    </LinearLayout> 

</ViewFlipper>
```

code for .java file

```
package com.examples.switchactivtybydragging;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.view.animation.*;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.ViewFlipper;

public class SwitchActivityByDraggingActivity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    private float downXValue;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        LinearLayout layMain = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_main);
        layMain.setOnTouchListener((OnTouchListener) this);
        Spinner spinnerCountries = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_country);
        @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
        ArrayAdapter countryArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
                    new String[] { "Canada", "USA" });
        spinnerCountries.setAdapter(countryArrayAdapter);
    }
    public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {

        // Get the action that was done on this touch event
        switch (arg1.getAction())
        {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            {
                // store the X value when the user's finger was pressed down
                downXValue = arg1.getX();
                break;
            }

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            {
                // Get the X value when the user released his/her finger
                float currentX = arg1.getX();            

                // going backwards: pushing stuff to the right
                if (downXValue < currentX)
                {
                    // Get a reference to the ViewFlipper
                     ViewFlipper vf = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.details);
                     // Set the animation
                      vf.setAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.push_left_out));
                      // Flip!
                      vf.showPrevious();
                }

                // going forwards: pushing stuff to the left
                if (downXValue > currentX)
                {
                    // Get a reference to the ViewFlipper
                    ViewFlipper vf = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.details);
                     // Set the animation
                     vf.setInAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.push_left_in));
                      // Flip!
                     vf.showNext();
                }
                break;
            }
        }

        // if you return false, these actions will not be recorded
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Please include the error that you're seeing - ideally the full stacktrace from logcat.

Comment: actually in my Android sdk .xml file for animation is not available..so it dont found push_left_in.xml and push_left_out.xml that i have used..so how can i get this in my sdk..

Comment: Where have you put your animation files?

Comment: i had installed installer_r11-windows.exe for android sdk..after installation it start sdk_manager.exe file and install all packages..but when i open the sdk than i havent found any animation file in the sdk..moreever it say that it should be present in platform directory of sdk but here it is empty..should i use android-sdk_r11-windows.zip instead of installer_r11-windows.exe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you haven't created the animations. For your code to work, you require animations in `res/anim/push_left_in.xml` and `res/anim/push_left_out.xml`. It is the absence of these files that is causing your error.

I have written a blog series about [Simple Animations](http://blog.stylingandroid.com/archives/129) which may help you to understand how to create these files, and what you need to put in them.